# Using webpack and react &times; becomes Ã— with minification

Tags: webpack, reactjs

I'm using webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin() to minify my React code.

This is my render function

```
return (
    <div id='columnPicker' className='modal fade' tabIndex='-1' role='dialog'>
        <div className='modal-dialog modal-sm' role='document'>
            <div className='modal-content'>
                <div className='modal-header'>
                    <button type='button' className='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
                    <h4 className='modal-title'>Column Picker</h4>
                </div>
                <div className='modal-body'>
                    <ul className='list-group'>
                        {listItems}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className='modal-footer'>
                    <div className='pull-right'>
                        <button type='button' className='btn btn-sm btn-primary' data-dismiss='modal' onClick={props.onSave}>Save</button>
                    </div>
                    <div className='pull-right'>
                        <button type='button' className='btn btn-link' data-dismiss='modal'>Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

The close button uses &times but when it actually renders I see

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Ã—</button>
```

If I remove webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin() it renders as one would expect.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You could try: `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    mangle: {
        except: ['&times;']
    }
})`

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it didn't work.  If I look at the generated minified react code it for some reason switches the unicode value for the times symbol to another unicode value.  For now I just switched to using the font awesome close symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying the charset in the HTML will preserve the correct character.

Try adding `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` (or whatever charset) to the meta tag on your html file.

Answer (score -2):

I've just had the same issue using angular-cli (V2.4.6). In this case the problem only happens in production mode.

Angular-cli uses webpack internally but provides no access to which options are used in production vs development mode.

Adding
    `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>`
also worked for me.